# How can I manipulate this object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#square a').click(function(e) {  
    // How is the e object structured
    }); 
})
```

I have a div with an id of square and links in that. When the links are clicked they trigger a game loop function. I need to know which id the click is coming from. There are five links within the square and each one has an id. Is there a better way to track this. Or should I have a function for each link with its own id but this doesn't seem DRY to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside an event handler you can refer to the DOM element the event was triggered on with `this`:

```
$('#square a').click(function(e) {  
    alert(this.id);
});
```

So jQuery makes it very convient to access the element.

If you have to execute different code based on the ID, I suggest to create some kind of map:

```
var actions = {
    action1: function() {

    },
    action2: function() {

    },
    ...
}
```

and then just execute the function from the map:

```
$('#square a').click(function(e) {  
    actions[this.id]();
});
```

Just make sure you give the elements meaningful IDs.

Comment: Not only do you need to give them meaningful IDs, you should try to keep them unique, as that is the rule. Additionally, @FelixKling good point on the closure, makes it even easier to maintain (if it does look a little funky)

Comment: Must be a mind reader. I knew how to get things working after this but your code method is much better ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `e` in your code is an event object. The docs for that [are here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Within an event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element that you have hooked the handler to (not wrapped in a jQuery instance). So for instance:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#square a').click(function(e) {  
        alert(this.href);
    }); 
});
```

...would show the `href` of the link that was clicked.

Since `click` events bubble up the DOM, and they also have a default behavior on `a` elements (following the link), you may particularly be interested in [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) (stop the event bubbling any further up the DOM) and [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (prevent the default action). You can get the effect of calling both of those if you simply return `false` out of your event handler, but sometimes you only want to do one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
<div id='square'>
  <a id='link1'>Go forward!</a><br />
  <a id='link2'>Look left</a><br />
  <a id='link3'>Stop!</a><br />
  <a id='link4'>Look right</a><br />
  <a id='link5'>Go back!!!</a>
</div>

$('#square > a').live('click',function(event){
  var whichLink = $(this).attr('id');

  if ( whichLink == 'link1' ) GoForward();
  if ( whichLink == 'link2' ) LookLeft();
  if ( whichLink == 'link3' ) Stop();
  if ( whichLink == 'link4' ) CantTouchThis();
  if ( whichLink == 'link5' ) Hammertime();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A good way to quickly check things like this is with the `console` of Firefox (Firebug), Chrome and Safari (I believe that Opera has something similar as well.):

If you run the following code on any web page with jQuery on it via the console of Firebug:

```
jQuery("body").click(function(e) { console.dir(e); });
```

You will see the following:
[image: Firebug output from the dir command]

T. J. has provided another **excellent** source as well (t[he jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).)

Comment: *"The best way to check things like this is with Firebug"* Enh, that will show you not only fairly standard things and the things that jQuery ensures are standardized, but a *lot* of Gecko-specific stuff as well. Firebug is very useful, but does inevitably show all the extensions that Gecko has on top of the DOM.

Comment: @T.J. -- an excellent point - I'll update the question to be less forceful.

Comment: @Sam -- I believe that Safari has a console with the same method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633/where-is-the-console-api-for-webkit-safari

Comment: Yup. @Sam, in Preferences | Advanced, tick the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" and close the preferences. Then you'll find on gear menu or whatever, there's a "Develop" menu with *lots* of fun stuff to play with. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#square a').click(function(e) {  
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get clicked element's id that has not been mentioned is through the event object and answers your question about `e` parameter:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#square a').click(function(e) {  
       alert(e.target.id);
    }); 
});
```

The advantage of using `e.target.id` is that you can obtain id of the **child object that was actually clicked on**, while `this.id` will always return id of the element click event handler was bound to.

Also, if you're going to use `this` there is no reason to declare `e`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#square a').click(function() {  
       alert(this.id);
    });
});
```