# Retrieving data fron JSON files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to use JQuery's JSONP feature to retrieve barometric pressure data from a website.

First, I used Yahoo! Pipes to convert the XML data to JSON. Then I tried to receive and use that data in an alert, but it didn't work. In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/), I have a simple, working example, but when I try use the more advanced JSON file, it doesn't work.

See also [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) by IBM.

Comment: **1.)** You have to choose jQuery in JSFiddle instead of (default) Mootools. **2.)** Open your browser's javascript console and see the occurring errors. **3.)** You haven't defined the callback function!

Comment: I get a 404 on that first link. The page is not found

Comment: @akellehe He also forgot `http://` in the link.

Comment: It says that `data.value` is undefined in the error console, even after adding the `http://` and changing to JQuery (which I had added in the resources).

Comment: it seems you are just learning javascript. i can only suggest for next time try to make tests in smaller increments. understand which parts fail and why. if you just write a bunch of code and then guess what the problem is you will always end up having misleading titles like in this question (really: i downvoted because the actual issue has absolutely nothing to do with the title). also you can look at my answer, i corrected your code and the alert spits out the pressure value. good luck with your project!

Comment: It's not that I am just learning JavaScript, but I am new to JSON and JQuery. I definitely learned a lot working on this.

Comment: I changed the name; I think it works a bit better for the community

Comment: BTW, here is the final product in case anyone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/7EPjH/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems in your code**

- You forget to include `http://` in your link

You need to try this (see `alert`. It will alert the title)

```
<div onClick="$.getJSON('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=467a55b506ba06b9ca364b1403880b65&_render=json&textinput1=40.78158&textinput2=-73.96648&_callback=?', function(data){alert(data.value.title)})">Click Me</div><!--I can't get this to work-->
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/7EPjH/12/)**

But its better to use like following:

```
<div class="loadjson">Click Me</div>


function barometer() {
    $.getJSON('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=467a55b506ba06b9ca364b1403880b65&_render=json&textinput1=40.78158&textinput2=-73.96648&_callback=?', function(data) {
        alert(data.value.title);
    })
}

$('div.loadjson').on('click', function() {
    barometer();
});
```

**Note:** `$.getJSON()` returns two `parameters` within `data` object.

```
     - 1st one is `count` that have integer value
     - 2nd one is `value`, which is an `Object`.
```

To get the **second parameter** you need to use `data.value`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/7EPjH/11/)**

Comment: Sorry, I don't have firebug. What is the point of adding the console.log? In your demo, clicking on the div still didn't bring up the alert. Thanks

Comment: @Ian if you're going to be doing JS development I think it would be strongly encouraged to learn firebug or how to use another browser's JavaScript console. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633/where-is-the-console-api-for-webkit-safari

Comment: @Ian I make my fiddle with `alert()`, but you should use to learn firebug

Comment: I don't use Firebug because I can just use the Firefox Dev Tools (and Firebug is one of the slowest Firefox addons). I see the alert now, but not with my way to get to the barometer,which means that `data.value.items.data.parameters.pressure.value` is incorrect. Any ideas on that? I checked the JSON file after running it through a JavaScript tidying program, but I can't figure out what is wrong with that path.

Comment: Actually, I;'ve got it working now. The only problem I am having is that when I get to `parameters`. There are two `parameters` under `data`, so how do I select the second one?

Comment: Got it by using `data[1].parameters` which worked perfectly. `data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.pressure.value`.

Comment: With deeply nested JSON figuring out the tree/path can cause headaches for some thankfully there are a few online tools like this one http://lovelogic.net/support_articles/JSON_XML_parser_demo.php that can decode XML and JSON into something that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

there were *many many many* problems with the code i fixed it and commented on the problems  inline ...

jsfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kritzikratzi/LQcVd/

```
function loadBarometerData(){
    // 1. it's not generally bad practice to put stuff in the 
    //    onClick listeners, but really... don't put such long code there! it's not readable ... 
    // 2. you were missing a "http://" and it was downloading
    //    jsfiddle.net/pipes.yahoo.com/....
    // 3. getJSON doesn't return a result immediately, you need to use callbacks for that!! 
    $.getJSON('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=467a55b506ba06b9ca364b1403880b65&_render=json&textinput1=40.78158&textinput2=-73.96648&_callback=?' ).success( barometer ); 
}; 

function barometer(data) {
    console.log( data );
    // 4. you had items instead of items[0]
    //    similar with data. 
    alert(data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.pressure.value);
};

function showPrice(data) {
    alert("Symbol: " + data.symbol[0] + ", Price: " + data.price);
}
​
```