# How to use console.log to print out how which function called a piece of code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

If I put `console.log()` inside a function, is there anything that I can put inside the `console.log()` statement to find out where the function was called from? Or is there some other way to find out how a function is called?

I'm trying to understand a relatively complex (complex for someone of my experience) piece of code, and it's hard to figure out what is calling a certain function. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever look at the profiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `console.trace()`? It prints out a stack trace.

Here's the [Firebug documentation](http://getfirebug.com/logging) on the function ([which is also supported in Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633/where-is-the-console-api-for-webkit-safari)):

> Just call console.trace() and Firebug will write a very informative
>   stack trace to the console. Not only will it tell you which functions
>   are on the stack, but it will include the value of each argument that
>   was passed to each function. You can click the functions or objects to
>   inspect them further.

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString())
```

Comment: `arguments.callee` throws errors in strict mode, and is considered deprecated. Don't use it anymore